# Exporting folder information from Shared Drive; Issue with pageToken

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm attempting to export the folder name, folder id, folder url, and filepath for folders within a Shared Drive.  This part works, but I'm limited to 100 items.  I'm attempting to use the pageToken/nextPageToken functionality to pull all items, but it doesn't seem to work and continues returning only 100 items.  I'm using the same basic structure as google uses in their [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) code for this purpose and was also referencing [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67300849) to a similar problem.

```
function getFolderURLs() {
  var folders, pageToken;
  var foldersArray = [["Folder Name", "Link", "Folder ID", "Filepath"]]
  do {
    try {
    var optionalArgs  = {
    supportsAllDrives: true,
    includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
    pageToken: pageToken,
    maxResults: 100,
    q: '"132vqY8oyd6xKpnxxxxxxxxxxx" in parents and trashed = false and mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"'
  }
  var folders = Drive.Files.list(optionalArgs);
  var allFolders = folders.items
  if (!allFolders || allFolders.length === 0) {
    Logger.log ('No folders found.');
    return
  }
  for (i = 0; i < allFolders.length; i++) {
    var folder = allFolders[i];
    var name = folder.title
    var link = folder.alternateLink
    var id = folder.id

    var parentID = Drive.Files.get(folder.id,{
      supportsAllDrives: true,
    }).parents[0].id
    var parent = Drive.Files.get(parentID,{
      supportsAllDrives: true,
      includesItemsFromAllDrives: true,
    }).title
    var filepath = `${parent}/${name}`

    foldersArray.push([name, link, id, filepath])
  }
  pageToken = folders.nextPageToken;
} catch (err) {
  Logger.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
}
  }
   while (pageToken);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create('Clients Folder ID Listing');
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(1,1,foldersArray.length, 4).setValues(foldersArray)
    Logger.log(foldersArray)
}
```

Comment: Try this.  Before `do {` put `var pageToken = null;`.  In your script `pageToken` is undefined which may affect `Drive.Files.list(optionalArgs)`

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About `I'm attempting to export the folder name, folder id, folder url, and filepath for folders within a Shared Drive.`, in your script, `132vqY8oyd6xKpnxxxxxxxxxxx` of `"132vqY8oyd6xKpnxxxxxxxxxxx" in parents` is the drive ID of the shared Drive and you want to retrieve all files and folders in a shared Drive? Or, you want to retrieve the file list just under the specific folder?

Comment: @TheWizEd and upvoted user If I misunderstood it, please tell me. I thought that in OP's showing script, `pageToken` has already been declared at `var folders, pageToken;` just under the line of `function getFolderURLs() {` and, this is updated by `pageToken = folders.nextPageToken;` in the do-while loop. How about this?

Comment: @TheWizEd Thanks for that idea; I originally had pageToken defined as null and changed it later.  I tried defining it as null prior to do { and it still only put 100 records in the spreadsheet.

Comment: @TheWizEd The id listed in the query is the id for the subfolder in the shared drive.  I only want the information in that folder and not all folders within the shared drive.

Comment: @Ted Perry If your comment of `@TheWizEd The id listed in the query is the id for the subfolder in the shared drive. I only want the information in that folder and not all folders within the shared drive.` is the answer to my comment, are there multiple subfolders in the subfolder you want to retrieve and do you want to retrieve all files and folders including the subfolders? Or, do you want to retrieve the files and folders just under the specific folder you want to retrieve?

Comment: @Tanaike There are many subfolders within the folder ID in which I'm searching.  I'm hoping to retrieve the information for the folders and files just in the folder ID in which I'm searching, but I wasn't sure if it was go to deeper levels, so I am including the filepath variable (parent title/file title) to ensure that I can manipulate the output to get only the results I need if it returns more than I want.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `so I am including the filepath variable (parent title/file title) to ensure that I can manipulate the output to get only the results I need if it returns more than I want.`. For example, you want to retrieve all files and folders including all subfolders in the specific folder of the shared Drive. If my understanding is correct, in this case, what is `if it returns more than I want`?

Comment: @Tanaike I wasn't certain whether, once I get it working with more than 100 records, it will return only the files and folders within the subfolder in the shared drive (the id referenced in the query) or whether it would also return the files and folders within each subfolder.  Because of this, I added the "filepath" variable to be able to easily tell if any results had been returned that I don't ultimately want.  Because the results so far have been limited to 100 records, I still don't know what records will ultimately be included.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the folder list in the specific folder.
- The specific folder has multiple subfolders.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

When I saw your script, `Drive.Files.get` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost might be high. And, in your script, it seems that the subfolders cannot be retrieved.

In this case, how about the following sample script? In this answer, I used a Google Apps Script library for retrieving the file and folder list using Google Apps Script. I created this library for like this situation.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install library.

Please install the Google Apps Script library. You can see the method for installing it at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/FilesApp#how-to-install).

#### 2. Enable Drive API.

This script uses Drive API. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

#### 3. Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID.

  const obj = FilesApp.getAllFoldersInFolder(folderId);
  if (obj.id.length == 0) return;
  const foldersArray = [["Folder Name", "Link", "Folder ID", "Filepath"], ...obj.name.map((e, i) => {
    const folderName = e.pop();
    const folderId = obj.id[i].pop();
    return [folderName, `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/${folderId}`, folderId, e.join("/")];
  })];
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('Clients Folder ID Listing').getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, foldersArray.length, 4).setValues(foldersArray);
}
```

- When this script is run, the folder list is retrieved from the specific folder. In this case, the subfolders are included. And, the values of `"Folder Name", "Link", "Folder ID", "Filepath"` are put into the created Spreadsheet.
- In this script, the folder list in the shared drive can be retrieved. When I tested this, I confirmed that a folder list including more than 100 folders could be retrieved.

### Reference:

- [FilesApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/FilesApp): Google Apps Script library.

Comment: I appreciate the response here.  I think that this solution would work for my use case.  That said, I'm hesitant to use a custom library for this project as I don't have the necessary knowledge to do my due diligence regarding the security.  I'm sure that you have no malicious intent and, were this a personal project, I would have far fewer reservations!  Is what I'm trying to accomplish not possible with the native google functionality?  It certainly seems that it would be from their resources.

Comment: @Ted Perry Thank you for replying. First, I deeply apologize that I created a Google Apps Script library and I used it for resolving your question. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. About `Is what I'm trying to accomplish not possible with the native google functionality?`, the library can be seen and downloaded. When you saw it, you can see a script created with `the native google functionality`. I created this using Google Apps Script. For example, you can use the Google Apps Script library by copying and pasting the script of the library to your script.